# Getting the source URL of image in Media Gallery Module

Tags: theming

I need one more thing to get my custom lightbox running in [the Media Gallery module for Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery).

The link that is clicked which leads to a custom page which contains the image is at this moment the following:

```
l($image, $link_path, array('html' => TRUE, 'attributes' => $attributes)) : $image;
```

The thing is that I want to link directly to the image, and not to a page where the image is on! I know that this is hard to understand so I'll try to clarify. At this moment, when you click the link you will be directed to something like this:
/media-gallery/detail/xxx/xxxxx

But I want it to link to the image itself (e.g. /files/folder.1.JPG) and I can't seem to find where the image is transformed into a page on itself. Does anyone have ANY idea? I would be soooo grateful!

Thanks a lot you guys.
EDIT: I have found that the generated link can be edited by the following snippet of code in colorbox-display.js:

```
var $ = jQuery, $galleries, $gallery, href, $links, $link, $dummyLinksPre, $dummyLinksPost, i, j;
    // Add a colorbox group for each media gallery field on the page.
    $galleries = $('.field-name-media-gallery-media');
    for (i = 0; i < $galleries.length; i++) {
      $gallery = $($galleries[i]);
      $links = $('a.sbEnabled', $gallery);
      $dummyLinksPre = $gallery.parent().find('ul:has(a.shadowbox-supplemental-link.pre)');
      $dummyLinksPost = $gallery.parent().find('ul:has(a.shadowbox-supplemental-link.post)');
      $dummyLinksPost.appendTo($gallery);
      $links = $links.add('a', $dummyLinksPre).add('a', $dummyLinksPost);
      $links.attr('rel', 'shadowbox-' + i);
      for (j = 0; j < $links.length; j++) {
        // Change the link href to point to the lightbox version of the media.
        $link = $($links[j]);
        href = $link.attr('href');
        $link.attr('href', href.replace(/\/detail\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/, '/lightbox/$1/$2'));
      }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't bother to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you're looking to override is hard coded into the `template_preprocess_media_gallery_media_item_thumbnail()` function in the Media Gallery module.

Fortunately, as it's a preprocess hook for a theme function, you can yourself override it in your site's theme. It does mean having to duplicate some code from the original preprocess function, and also another theme function so you can add the `rel` attribute, but it's not too much. You'll also need to implement `hook_js_alter()` to remove the colorbox js the the Media Gallery module adds by default.

Place the following code in your theme's template.php file and replace all occurrences of `THEMENAME` with your theme's name:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_media_gallery_media_item_thumbnail(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  // Only make the changes for images, no other media type.
  if (strtolower($element['#bundle']) != 'image') {
    return;
  }

  $format = $element['#media_gallery_entity']->media_gallery_format[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  $lightbox = is_numeric(strpos($format, 'lightbox')) ? TRUE : FALSE;

  /*
   I'M PRESUMING HERE THAT YOU'RE ADDING THE SHADOWBOX SCRIPT USING ANOTHER 
   METHOD (PERHAPS IN THE THEME'S .info FILE). IF THAT'S NOT THE CASE JUST 
   UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE AND CHANGE THE PATH TO ADD IT HERE

   if ($lightbox) {
     $element['file']['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEMENAME') . '/path/to/shadowbox.js';
   }
  */ 

  // Get the rendered file without annoying DIV wrappers.
  $element['file'] = array('#theme' => 'media_gallery_file_field_inline', '0' => $element['file']);
  $image = drupal_render($element['file']);

  $gallery_id = $element['#media_gallery_entity']->nid;
  $media_id = $element['#file']->fid;

  // Add a class that is a more targeted version of what template_preprocess()
  // automatically adds for this theme hook, to enable per-type (e.g., video vs.
  // image) styling.
  $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('media_gallery_media_item_thumbnail_' . $element['#file']->type);

  // Add a class for the wrapper.
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'media-gallery-item-wrapper';

  // Create an array of variables to be added to the main thumbnail link.
  $link_vars = array();
  $link_vars['image'] = $image;


  // THIS IS WHERE YOU MAKE THE CHANGE TO THE LINK PATH. YOU MENTIONED THAT
  // YOU'VE ALREADY MANAGED TO ADD THE 'rel' ATTRIBUTE THAT YOU NEED SO I WON'T
  // ADD THAT HERE
  // Old code: $link_vars['link_path'] = "media-gallery/detail/$gallery_id/$media_id";

  // New code:
  $style_name = 'media_gallery_large'; // Name of the image style for the full sized image you want to link to
  $url = image_style_url($style_name, $element['#file']->uri);
  $link_vars['link_path'] = $url;
  $link_vars['rel'] = 'shadowbox'; // The rel attribute
  // End new code


  $link_vars['classes'] = array('media-gallery-thumb');
  $link_vars['title'] = $element['#bundle'] == 'image' ? t('View larger image') : t('Watch video');
  // Add the image as a link to the detailed view
  $variables['media_gallery_item'] = theme('media_gallery_item', $link_vars);

  // Set the variables to theme the metadata.
  $meta_vars = array();
  $meta_vars['location'] = $element['#media_gallery_entity']->media_gallery_image_info_where[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  $meta_vars['title'] = isset($element['media_title']) ? $element['media_title'][0]['#markup'] : '';
  $meta_vars['link_path'] = $link_vars['link_path'];

  // Theme the metadata.
  $variables['media_gallery_meta'] = theme('media_gallery_meta', $meta_vars);
}

function THEMENAME_media_gallery_item($variables) {
  $image = $variables['image'];
  $link_path = $variables['link_path'];
  $attributes = array();
  if (!empty($variables['classes'])) {
    $attributes['class'] = $variables['classes'];
  }
  if (!empty($variables['title'])) {
    $new_image = str_replace(array('title=""', 'alt=""'), array('', ''), $image);
    $image = str_replace('/>', ' title="'.$variables['title'].'" alt="'.$variables['title'].'" />', $new_image);;
  }

  // Below is the only change to this function, just to add the rel attribute.
  if (!empty($variables['rel'])) {
    $attributes['rel'] = 'shadowbox';
  }

  // Add sliding door top div and wrappers
  $item = '<div class="media-gallery-item"><div class="top"><div class="top-inset-1"><div class="top-inset-2"></div></div></div><div class="gallery-thumb-outer"><div class="gallery-thumb-inner">';
  // Create a link around the image
  $item .= empty($variables['no_link']) ? l($image, $link_path, array('html' => TRUE, 'attributes' => $attributes)) : $image;
  // Add sliding door bottom div and close wrappers
  $item .= '</div></div><div class="bottom"><div class="bottom-inset-1"><div class="bottom-inset-2"></div></div></div></div>';
  return $item;
}

function THEMENAME_js_alter(&$js) {
  // Remove the media gallery colorbox js. It interferes with the rel attribute.
  if (isset($js['sites/all/modules/media_gallery/colorbox-display.js'])) {
    unset($js['sites/all/modules/media_gallery/colorbox-display.js']);
  }
}
```

I've added some comments to the code to explain what's happening so it might be worth giving the code a quick glance over.

After you've cleared Drupal's caches you should get exactly what you're after :)

Comment: I think you are getting close, but I think you misuderstood me:
As I can make up from your code, I do want the direct URL to the image but not when you click on the image when it is in a lightbox, but only when it is still a thumbnail. You see, there is a default lightbox (colorbox) but I hate it! (for editing reasons) So I want to use my own (shadowbox). To integrate this, I need to add a rel attribute to the thumbnail (done), which is a link, AND change the default destination of it (which is `media-gallery/detail/$gallery_id/$media_id`) to the uri to the image (ex. /files/picture.jpg)

Comment: Ah ok, so you want to change the actual link path of the anchor wrapping the thumbnail, and get rid of the colorbox js in favour of your own? There's a theme you can override for that too but before i dig it out can you confirm I'm on the right track?

Comment: That's right. At this moment the link is something like this: `<a href="www.website.com/media-gallery/detail/120/005" class="media-gallery-thumb" rel="shadowbox"><img src="www.website.com/sites/default/files/styles/media_gallery_thumbnail/public/P1060040.JPG"></a>` 
but I want it to be: `<a href="www.website.com/sites/default/files/styles/media_gallery_large/public/P1060040.JPG" class="media-gallery-thumb" rel="shadowbox"><img src="www.website.com/sites/default/files/styles/media_gallery_thumbnail/public/P1060040.JPG"></a>`

Note the differences between the thumb and large directory!

Comment: Gotcha. Ironically that's what I thought you meant originally so I've already worked out how to do that, I'll whip some code up and put it in the answer

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot man! (But please put very clear instructions, because I am really getting tired of this! I've been trying things for ages now and still to no avail! I am glad that I could finally put a 100 bounty on here!

Comment: @BramVanroy I've updated the answer, the code in there now should just be a drop-in solution but let me know if you have any problems :) p.s. great choice of lightbox, shadowbox is my preferred solution too

Comment: You are really the hero of today! Thanks a thousand billion times man! I gladly give some of my reputation to you! If you happen to have any idea how I can make it possible that users like a photograph (social media: FB, twitter, g+) but that they actually like a page with the picture on (the page we tried to avoid :p (this one: media-gallery/detail/$gallery_id/$media_id) I would understand if you don't have time to look at this or if you don't understand my question. But please do reply, so that I know whether I should make a new topic or not (I am out of reputation so I can't give more :( )

Comment: (and I am able to give you the bounty in 5 hours!)

Comment: Don't mention it I know how frustrating it can be to track these things down! I think it would be perfectly possible to add a like button that links to the other URL but it depends how you want to do it (which js library you want to use, where exactly you want the like button to appear, etc.). I would start a new question that refers back to this one, and be as descriptive as you possibly can about what you want to accomplish, and give as much detail as you can about how you're thinking about going about it. If you do I'll gladly have a look over and see if I can help :)

Comment: Oh, and don't worry about not being able to offer more bounties on questions, that's not really what motivates people to answer on this site; it's all about sharing the knowledge baby!

Comment: I wish I could help more, but unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with Drupal. I am quite active on stackOverflow (jQuery, CSS & HTML). It's a pity I can't use the reputation I have there on drupal.stackexchange! I will first try some things myself and if that doesn't work out, I will post a new topic - and possibly post a note over here. Thanks again Clive, I really appreciate it A LOT!

Comment: At least, this time the bounty will be assigned. `:)`

Comment: @Clive There, bounty given! I know I am being a pain in the ass right now, but maybe you know how to solve this. Everything works now as I wanted it to be, BUT when Presentation settings are set to 'Show media on a full page' (I use this for my movie clips), the theme still looks for the file's URL - but doesnt find it. I know I haven't asked you to implement this - but I completely forgot. An example can be found here: http://www.denotenbalkers.be/filmpjes/2007

If it is possible, fetching the youtube code is fine as well (so I can embed it in my lightbox)

I am so sorry to bother...

Comment: @BramVanroy Sorry for the late reply, I've added a couple of lines to the top of the `THEMENAME_preprocess_media_gallery_media_item_thumbnail()` function which will stop the function from make changes to any thumbnails that aren't for an image media type, I think that'll do the trick :)

Comment: You sir, are really THE man. Thanks a thousand times! Really, THANKS!

Comment: @Clive Hi there Clive. I have a new post concerning the idea I mentioned before. If you have time I would appreciate it if you could come and say 'ullo ;) http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28253/clicking-on-an-image-in-a-lightbox-returns-to-media-page

Comment: @BramVanroy I saw it a minute ago actually, it made me smile...when I was hacking this together the first time round I thought you'd probably want to do that eventually ;) I'm a bit tied up at work today but I'll have a look tonight/tomorrow and see what I can come up with

Comment: @Clive Thanks a lot, take your time! It is in no hurry. :)

Comment: @Clive Hey Clive! Just wondering if you could help me with that other question I posted. It's getting awfully poor attention :( http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28253/clicking-on-an-image-in-a-lightbox-returns-to-media-page